# android : Display image in imageview from another imageview source?

Tags: android, image, android-imageview

I have some imageView in my app, one of imageview is parent image,the function of parent image is display image from another imageview child if was click.

[image]

If image B1 click then source image of ImageView B1 show in imageView A and another imageView B can do like B1 if clicked, how I achieve that?

i Use this code to show image in imageview B.

```
private class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter{

        private View view;

        public CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
            view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window,
                    null);
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

            if (MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker != null
                    && MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
                MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker.hideInfoWindow();
                MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker.showInfoWindow();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) { 
            MapV2InfoWindow.this.marker = marker;

            String url = null;

            if (marker.getId() != null && markers != null && markers.size() > 0) {
                if ( markers.get(marker.getId()) != null &&
                        markers.get(marker.getId()) != null) {
                    url = markers.get(marker.getId());
                }
            }
            final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));

            if (url != null && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
                    && !url.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options,
                        new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,
                                    View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                                super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view,
                                        loadedImage);
                                getInfoContents(marker);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }


            return view;
        }
}
```

I get error

```
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at com.ltvie.chatkrawala.MapV2InfoWindow$1.onInfoWindowClick(MapV2InfoWindow.java:125)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$10.e(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.f$a.onTransact(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at eiy.a(SourceFile:82)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.e.bl.b(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.ay.o.am_(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.ay.o.a(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.ay.bg.b(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.ay.bc.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.bo.g.onSingleTapConfirmed(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at maps.bo.i.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
03-24 15:35:54.099: E/AndroidRuntime(8412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks.

Comment: Show your code in MapV2InfoWindow.java line 125.

Comment: bmImgInfoWindow = ((BitmapDrawable) imgFotoPpInfowindow.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                 imgFotoPpPosMap.setImageBitmap(bmImgInfoWindow);

Comment: actually i want to send source of imageview in infowindow to another imageview

Answer (score 1):

Just do this.

```
imageViewA.setImageDrawable( imageViewB.getDrawable() );
```

Comment: i get return null value..I update my question, see edit

Answer (score 0):

Implement onClick for your activity and do below stuff on **onClick** listener:

```
switch (key) {
        case R.id.b1:
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageViewB1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageViewA.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;

        case R.id.b2:
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageViewB2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageViewA.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;

        case R.id.b3:
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageViewB3.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
imageViewA.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```